# Function taking a function returning a generic type is not typesafe

Tags: typescript-generics

I experience this when using React hooks, but it is a general TypeScript question.

You can see it in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MA8AVAfACjgLhhwEpksNSsBvAKBnpgCcBTKAV0bHhIG4aBfGjSgBPAA7MYAJWYQ2AG1ipaDGACMAho0Jg2AWzXNGfVQhAB%20fLoNG%20gmqEixojDWADmk1GbQy5i3BIyFQYWdk4YENV6TW0YABYAJgAaOmiYjQAvQgBGFJgAegKYAHcACxEYAEsIGCgympgxRhAxGA15eRASgBNzNPSAMQB5YdyAZkLitjFagEkYPSr3Mth6qrAAaxgFiFY6sskzJpaxZPU2WF2JTuYe6tgSlo8BmEF%20YiFHaBhmAA8JMAoHcUPBEDgSPg-AooMFXmEOFwotFYvgkql0vQRmMYHkpgdGo0wCBYB0ur1zuUqsAytVauUNFdSgDmEC7q93sQgA)

When I use the generic parameter which I finds most intuitive the function I pass in isn't completely typesafe. As long as it returns an object with the props in T the compiler is happy, but I can also add props that are not part of T. This becomes a problem when T has some optional props, because I can miss spell them and not know it.

If I instead set the return type explicit on the function I pass in, everything works as expected, but this is not an intuitive usage when the function I call have a generic parameter.

Can someone please explain why the compiler is allowing this?

```
const foo = <T>(f: ()=>T) => {
    return f();
};

type Result = {
    bar: number;
    foo?:number;
}

const strange = foo<Result>(() => {
    return {
        bar: 42,
        baz: 12, // why is this prop allowd?
        FOO: 13 // ups I might think I set the foo prop, but I spelled it wrong
    };
});

const expected = foo((): Result => {
    return {
        bar:42,
        FOO: 12 // this is not allowd, which is what I wxpected
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) is triggered only for **"fresh"** object literal.
The freshness of an object literal is lost in case of type assertion and type widening.

in `strange` function, there is a type widening on the return type [(see issue #241)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241). So excess properties are valid.

```
const strange = foo<Result>(() => {
    // type widening occurs here
    // freshness is lost
    // No excess property check triggered
    return {
        bar: 42,
        baz: 12, // excess property allowed
        FOO: 13  // excess property allowed
    };
});
```

in the `expected` function, there is no type widening since the return type is explicitly specified. the freshness of the object literal is maintained, and the excess property check is triggered

```
const expected = foo((): Result => {
    // No type assertion
    // object literal is fresh
    // Excess property check is triggered
    return {
        bar:42,
        FOO: 12 // this is not allowd, which is what I wxpected
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know why it is like this? In what situations do you actually want this behavior?

Comment: Without return type widening, this would fail: `const a = () => ({ x: 3, y: 4 }); const b: () => { x: number } = a`.

Comment: Yes and I would want that because a is returning  something that isn’t a `{ x: number }`. If I wanted a to used like you suggested I would add `[key: string]: any` To the return type of b.